# Store files in SQL

Tags: architecture, blob, software-design

I'm looking for the best approach to storing mostly small and sensitive files in DB. Since part of the files will be more than 0.5MB (but still less than 2MB) I'm going to create a separate DB for the files to decrease the general DB performance. Also, I need to keep in mind that the DBs must support deletion and archiving.

What else should be taken into account or perhaps there are ready-made templates for such situations?